# QEBCDIC - Translation of Exclamation mark is not as expected

Tags: ibm-midrange

I've a server side socket program that is running on an IBM i box.  This server program reads ASCII data that is coming from a linux client, written in java.  Before using the incoming data, the server program calls the QDCXLATE program, using QEBCDIC table, to translate the incoming ASCII data into EBCDIC.  As far as I know, everything is translated correctly except the ! character, which is x'21' in ASCII.  For some reason, QEBCDIC is translating x'21' into x'4F'.  I lookup the EBCDIC table in the web and see that the ! character should have a hex value of 5A.  Any idea why this IBM supplied table is translating it to x'4F'?  Should I change this translation table to translate x'21' to x'5A' or should I make a copy of it and make the change in the copied version and change the program to use it to perform the translation?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for QDCXLATE recommends against using that API. They suggest to use iconv instead. I tried calling QDCXLATE with table QEBCDIC with my job CCSID set to 37, and I saw that the ! character was translated to the | character. When I ran my program with my job CCSID set to 500, the ! character was translated correctly. Then I tried the QTCPEBC table, and the ! character converted correctly with CCSID 37 but not with CCSID 500.

So it looks like QDCXLATE doesn't take the job CCSID into account.

What language are you calling QDCXLATE from? Maybe there is an easier way to convert from ASCII to EBCDIC.

Comment: It is a C program that written by someone long time ago.  Unfortunately, I'm not a strong c programmer.  I actually found this from ibm website: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_8.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/r_deeadvrf_Conversion_Table_Irregularities.html

Comment: Hello Barbara,  Would it be wise to simply change the QEBCDIC table to translate the !, [, and ] characters correctly?

Comment: This particular server program only deals with keyable character.  From what I can see, the QAEUSBB1 table seems to be the best suited for this.  I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: I don't think you should change the QEBCDIC table. If you want to change it, make a copy and change the copy.

Answer (score 0):

*Which* EBCDIC? EBCDIC is not one code page, but multiple. For instance, [CCSID 37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037) has ! at x'5A', while [CCSID 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_500) has it at x'4F'. There are *hundreds* of EBCDIC code pages and the set of *invariant* characters (those that don't change across code pages) is rather small: only A-Z, 0-9, and a few special characters — not even a-z are invariant as some Japanese code pages replace these with Kanji characters.